# What is a proper way decode frame to image bitmap in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, opencv, blazor, rtsp-client

I use RtspClientSharp for receiving frames from the remote Ip camera in Blazor server Application. And now I need to convert the received frame to a bitmap (imageByte in the next expression) for use as a source in the img tag , something as follows:

```
imageSrc = "Data:Image/jpg; base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)
```

Can anyone give me an example of which function can be used from OpenCVSharp and with what parameters to convert rawFrame (h.264) -> imageBytes? Or what to read and in what direction to move. The topic is new to me and the deadline is soon